# disable ipv4 or ipv6 in local area connection - batch file

Tags: batch-file, ipv4

I have multiple NIC's some use IPv4 others IPV6, by using batch file I am trying to figure out how i can disable IP4 on the NICs that solely use IPV6 and also disable IPV6 on the NICs that use IPV4.  currently performing this manually within NIC properties by un-ticking the box of IPv4 or IPv6.

It seems netsh is unable to do this - any ideas how this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use [nvspbind](http://ss64.com/nt/nvspbind.html) . Though it is not supported anymore is the only command line tool provided by MS capable to do this.

This for example should disable IPv6 on "Local Area Connection" :

```
nvspbind.exe /d "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip6
```

And this is for IPv4

```
nvspbind.exe /d "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip
```